# Add explicit type to flatmap

Tags: swift, combine

When uncommenting the code in the following code block I get the following error.

`Cannot infer return type for closure with multiple statements; add explicit type to disambiguate`

But I can't figure out the syntax for explicitly adding a type. How do I do it?

```swift
let path:String = path ?? Self.path
let publisher: AnyPublisher<[Self]?, Error> = NetworkableManager.getAll(path: path) 
    .flatMap {
//     if path == "menus" {
//        print("It's a menu")
//     }
       return StorableManager.shared.saveAll($0)
                
    }
    .merge(with: StorableManager.shared.fetchAll(predicate: filters))
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: `.flatMap { item -> ReturnType in ...` where `item` represents the output of `getAll` and `ReturnType` the output type of `saveAll`

Comment: See my tutorial https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/tricksandtips.html for how to avoid that sort of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide a whole lot of information about the classes involved so I mocked something up to create the playground example below.

The bit that I have added is in the closure of the `flatmap` operator.  Basically I told the compiler what type that closure will return using the fragment `input -> Future<[String], Error>`. To come up with that line I had to know the return type of `StorageManager.shared.saveAll(items: input)` so I used the value my mocked up sample returns.

Your return value may be different.

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class StorageManager {
    static let shared = StorageManager()

    init() {
    }

    func saveAll(items: [String]) -> Future<[String], Error> {
        Future<[String], Error> { fulfill in
                fulfill(.success(items))
        }
    }
}

struct NetworkManager {
    static func getAll(path: String) -> Future<[String], Error> {
        Future<[String], Error> { fulfill in
            fulfill(.success(["Duck", "Cow", "Chicken"]))
        }
    }
}

let path : String = "some path"
let publisher : AnyPublisher<[String], Error> =
    NetworkManager.getAll(path: path)
        .flatMap { input -> Future<[String], Error> in

             if path == "menus" {
                print("It's a menu")
             }

            return StorageManager.shared.saveAll(items: input)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: Thanks! It was mainly the line ` input -> Future<[String], Error> in` that I needed. Despite an hour + of searching I couldn't find the syntax to declare the return type of a flatMap

Comment: It's not so much the return type of `flatmap` as it is the return type of the block/closure that you pass as a parameter to flatmap.  Look under the heading of "Closure Expression Syntax" at https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html